# JQuery - Fastest possible way of appending list items to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have some jquery that works fine, but I'd like to highly optimize it. Basically I'm
doing standard appending list items to unordered lists. Can anyone recommend the fastest
way to optimise the following code e.g. createDocumentFragment ?

```
for (key in data) {
     li = $('<li><span class="item">' + data[key]["Name"] + '</span><img src=' +   options.deleteIcon + ' alt="remove" class="delete"/></li>');
     $('.item', li).data('ID', data[key]["Id"]);
     $(list).append(li);
}
```

Comment: According to the description, 'list' is an unordered list (ul) DOM element.

Comment: @Chris - but is it just created, as part of this operation...or already in the DOM?

Comment: Because I had nothing better to do (...that I *wanted* to do, anyway...) I figured I'd put together a simple comparison of creating elements and `appendTo()` (slightly different to your own approach). This suggests that creating elements with `$(document.createElement('li'))` is consistently faster than using the jQuery method of `$('<li></li>')`. Whether this is transferable to your own use is another matter entirely, of course. [Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/57fvJ/).

Answer (score 5):

```
var sb = new Array();

for (key in data) {
   sb.push('<li><span class="item" id="', data[key]['Id'], '">', data[key]["Name"], '</span><img src=', options.deleteIcon, ' alt="remove" class="delete"/></li>')}

$(list).append(sb.join(""));
```

Comment: why is this the fastest?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reducing the number of writes to the DOM to just one. By that, I mean storing the list into a temporary variable and then appending the entire list in a single operation. Also, instead of using `.attr` to set the ID of each element, you can use concatenation as you have used it to set the text of each LI.

```
var tmpList = '';
for (key in data) {
     li = '<li><span class="item" id="' + data[key]['Id'] + '">' + data[key]["Name"] + '</span><img src=' +   options.deleteIcon + ' alt="remove" class="delete"/></li>';
     tmpList += li;
}

// if you are appending to an existing list, use append
// if you have just built one up from scratch, just use `.html`
$(list).append(tmpList);
```

I would recommend reading this:

[Optimizing JavaScript For Execution Speed](http://archive.devwebpro.com/devwebpro-39-20030514OptimizingJavaScriptforExecutionSpeed.html)

From the article:

> Unlike other programming languages,
>   JavaScript manipulates web pages
>   through a relatively sluggish API, the
>   DOM. Interacting with the DOM is
>   almost always more expensive than
>   straight computations. After choosing
>   the right algorithm and data structure
>   and refactoring, your next
>   consideration should be minimizing DOM
>   interaction and I/O operations.

Comment: @karim79 - one more change I'd make, try and avoid global variables...I realize the OP did this, but I *hope* it's unintentional.

Comment: I get "page not found" for that link on optimization.  Is adding a load of HTML code really faster than direct DOM manipulation then?  I would have thought a `clone()` on a template, change the text in the `<span>` and append would be quicker.  Could do with some profiling.

Comment: I'd use innerHTML and avoid jQuery

Comment: Thanks everyone, the one point everyone seems to miss is that I'm associating the Id with the DOM element <span class="item">... using the jquery.data method. This isn't to be confused the the ID attribute for the span element. Because of this I'm not sure how the concatenation would work as I understand that I need to have a reference to the DOM element to set the data on it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you could make one large chunk of li elements and then append them in a single operation instead of appending them one at time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the one point everyone seems to miss is that I'm associating the Id with the DOM element ... using the jquery.data method. This isn't to be confused the the ID attribute for the span element. Because of this I'm not sure how the concatenation would work as I understand that I need to have a reference to the DOM element to set the data on it. Is this correct?